# Curl refuses to clear cached session / cookies

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I am having problems with a PHP page using CURL not clearing its session cookies. Code is as follows:

```
    $crl = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "");

    //curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $page = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
```

As you can see I've tried several functions to clear the session. I also commented out the cookie file. But still the script retrives the page with the same cookie information it was using earlier, when I had the cookiefile enabled.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure curl is sending a cookie header? Can you sniff the TCP traffic to the $url host to see what exactly is being sent?

Comment: I'm not positive, but that is the only CURL related code and the cookie file is definitely commented out. Not sure how to proceed with sniffing the TCP traffic though that sounds like a good way to test that.

Comment: Why did you tag this with CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending a timestamp to your $url variable: $url . '?t=' . time().

I usually try to use the cookiejar for this, and I allways try to set both options:

```
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
```

When you enable this, is cookies.txt writeable?